# What are the limitations on filenames saved to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, filenames, nsfilemanager

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.  Is there a limit to the number of characters that can be used in a filename and/or is there a restriction on what characters can be used in a file name saved by an iPhone app?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [underlying filesystem is HFS+](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/Classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009069) which limits filenames to [255 UTF-16 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus).  There may be additional restrictions on the filenames but I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this site](http://www.xvsxp.com/files/forbidden.php), the only forbidden character on HFS+ volumes (which as Michael Greene stated is the underlying filesystem on the iPhone) is the colon character. You may also have some trouble using the '/' character since OS X tends to treat those as directory separators, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the colon (:), a folder separator from HFS days still applies but it is better to avoid such characters.